# Framer Motion allow scrolling when animation is over

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I am trying to create this sequence. When the user Starts scrolling down I am trying to active animate a full page div into a rectangle

1. Div becomes rectange on the right of the page
2. Moves -300px on the left and a few other things

I have achieved this but I cannot figure out how to have the container to be 'sticky' and then when the animation ends to turn back to position: 'static' so the container doesnt move while I animate.

Also I want to stop the scroll from happening while the animation is fired. Can you provide me with some directiosn to uderstand a few things better?

```
'use client'
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { motion, useScroll, useAnimation, useAnimate } from "framer-motion"
import { scroll } from "framer-motion"

import Image from "next/image";
import styles from '../_styles/ScrollingAnimation.module.css'
const IntroScroll2 = () => {

    const [scope, animate] = useAnimate();
    const [fireAnimation, setFireAnimation] = useState(false);
    const [scrollY, setScrollY] = useState(0);

    const handleAnimate = async () => {
        await animate('#image', {
            width: 700,
            height: 400,
            originX: 0,
            position: 'sticky',
            top: 0,
            transition: { ease: [0.44, 0.04, 0.76, 0.83] }
        },)
        await animate('#image', { y: 20 }, { ease: [0.2, 0.8, 0.19, 0.83] })
        await animate('#image', { x: -300 })
        await animate('#image', { y: 0 }, { ease: [0.2, 0.8, 0.19, 0.83],  })
    }

   

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleScroll = () => {
            setScrollY(window.scrollY);
        };

        window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
        };
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
       
        if (scrollY > 0.56) {
            setFireAnimation(true)
        } else {
            setFireAnimation(false)
        }
    }, [scrollY])

    useEffect(() => {
        if(fireAnimation) {
            handleAnimate()
        }   
      
    }, [fireAnimation])
   



  

    return (
        <div ref={scope}>
            <div className="animation-container">
                <div id="image" className="image-div" >
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="test">
                sefsefsf
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default IntroScroll2;
```